# Add two array values of same name using script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

I need to multiply two values of a and b and display in c. Also I need to display the addition value of c using script. Please check my code below:

**HTML:**

```
        <table border="1" id="table" class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>a</th>
                <th>b</th>
                <th>c</th>
            </tr>

                <?php
                $select= "SELECT * from table where id=1";
                            $result = mysql_query($select);
                            $row_count=1;
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
                ?>  
<tr>    
            <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['name_a']; ?>" name="name_a[]" class="name_a"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['code_a']; ?>" name="code_a[]" class="code_a"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="id_a[]" class="id_a" ></td>
</tr>
        <?php
        $row_count++;
        }
        ?>

</table>
    <input type="text" name="total" class="total">
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table').on('keyup', '.name_a', cal)
        .on('keyup', '.code_a', cal)
        .on('keyup', '.id_a', cal);

    function cal() {
        var $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
        name_a = $row.find('.name_a').val(),
        code_a = $row.find('.code_a').val(),
        id_a = $row.find('.id_a').val(),
        id_a_calc = name_a * code_a;

        $row.find('.id_a').val(id_a_calc)

    }
});
```

**OUTPUT**

```
a   b   c 
1   2   2
2   4   8
```

By the above script,I can multiply a and b and display in c.But how to add two values of 'c' and display in total text box.Need help

Comment: Aren't you missing `<tr>` and `</tr>` tags on each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#table').on('keyup', '.name_a', cal)
            .on('keyup', '.code_a', cal)
            .on('keyup', '.id_a', cal); 
    });

    function cal() {
        var $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
        name_a = $row.find('.name_a').val(),
        code_a = $row.find('.code_a').val(),
        id_a = $row.find('.id_a').val(),
        id_a_calc = name_a * code_a;

        $row.find('.id_a').val(id_a_calc);
        var total = 0;
        $(".id_a").each(function() {
           // console.log($(this).val());
            if($(this).val().length > 0){
            total += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
            }
        });
        $(".total").val(total);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this in `cal` after you update `$row.find('.id_a').val()`

```
var total = 0;
$(".id_a").each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
});
$(".total").text(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        var cValue = 0;
        $('#table tr td:nth-child(3)').each(function() { 
            cValue += parseInt($(this).html());
        });
        $("#total").val(cValue)
    }); 
});
```

jsfiddle example:-
http://jsfiddle.net/c2S5d/21/